# Create a price range from given min and max values

Tags: php, range

Given two values `$min` and `$max`, I want to create a price range for users to choose from.

### Example

```
$min = 849;
$max = 41259;
```

My thresholds are:

```
<10K
10K to 25K
25K to 40K
40K+
```

So, if my min value is 12000, the first one in the threshold will not come. Tried a couple of things, but none worked. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for not including the _tried a couple of things_ into your post?

Comment: I tried a couple of things that worked, Show us what didn't work and we can show you how to make it work

Comment: Well we are not here to think for you.

Comment: `if (){ ... }elseif () { ... }`

Comment: @ravisoni I don't need you to tell me that. There are better ways to ask a question or demand question update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the below function. This is for all those in the comments above asking what i did.

```
function getPriceFilter( $min, $max ) {
    $min = ( int ) str_replace( ',', '', $min );
    $max = ( int ) str_replace( ',', '', $max );

    $result = array();

    $limit = array(
        10000 => array(
            'Less than 10,000',
            '0^10000'),
        25000 => array(
            '10,001 to 25,000',
            '10001^25000'),
        40000 => array(
            '25,001 to 40,000',
            '25001^40000'),
        40001 => array(
            '40,000+',
            '40001^1000000')
    );

    $minCheck = 0;
    foreach( $limit as $key => $check ) {
        if( ! $minCheck ) {
            if( $min <= $key ) {
                $result[] = $check;
                $minCheck = 1;
            }
        } else {
            if( $max >= $key ) {
                $result[] = $check;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use for loop in PHP.

```
$min = 123;
$max = 345;
for($i=$min;$i<$max;$i++){
    echo $i."<br/>";
}
```

Change $min with minimum and $max with maximum.

UPDATE:

if you want that your first and last i.e. min and max values should not be displayed itself. You could use this code

```
$min = 123+1;
$max = 345-1;
for($i=$min;$i<$max;$i++){
    echo $i."<br/>";
}
```